# Unable to build react-native android app after updating to AndroidX and react-native version 0.59.10

Tags: react-native, androidx

I am getting the below error after updating my react-native version to 0.59.10 on android.

```
(0,react.memo) is not a function.(in '(0,_react.memo)(FastimageBase)')'),'(0,_react.memo)' is undefined)
```

My Package.json file is as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "@pusher/chatkit-client": "^1.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "esdoc": "^1.1.0",
    "esdoc-standard-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.4",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "password-validator": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-dynamic-cropper": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-email": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.24.1",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-imagepicker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-mixpanel": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-open-settings": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-pdf": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.2",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-share": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^8.0.11",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.5",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^1.3.1",
    "rollbar-react-native": "^0.5.0"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: If you are updating to AndroidX, I recommend you to update react native to 0.60.

Comment: Please change version by running following command:`npm install react-redux@6.0.1`

Comment: @MiltonBO I have tried this but there are some packages like "rollbar-react-native" that does not support autolinking yet.

Comment: @hongdevelop Updating the version worked. Thanks

Comment: @MohitManhas I wrote this comment on the answer. Can you choose mark 'V' of my answer to help others?

Comment: @hongdevelop I did and added some steps as well that i followed additionaly.

Comment: @MohitManhas  Thank you. Your additional information will be of great help to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change version by running following command:

```
`npm install react-redux@6.0.1 --save`
```

Make sure you have react version 16.8.3 and then reset cache before running app with

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```